# How to output topics and replies in bbpress as table?

Tags: wp-query, bbpress

I need to output the bbpress topic and reply loop in a table format. I'm having trouble finding how one might do this Are there any suggestions on how one might do this? Can this be done using wp_query or am I better off using the topics loop?